# Determine Swift Array Type

Tags: swift

I'm trying to determine the type of a collection using Swift. That is my goal. It does not appear to be supported by the new language so I tried to fall back on Objective-C. Collection generics is a new feature and I believe was only added for Swift interoperability.

Is anyone aware of a feature that will allow me to inspect the array type of `d`?

```
class SuperClass : NSObject { }

class SubClass: SuperClass { }

let a = SubClass()

if a.isKindOfClass(SuperClass) {
// this works as expected like objective-c
    print("yes") 
}

let b = Array<SubClass>()
if b.isKindOfClass(Array<SuperClass>)  { 
// error: value type of 'Array<SubClass>' has no member isKindOfClass
    print("yes")
}

if b is Array<SuperClass> {
// error: 'SuperClass' is not a subtype of 'SubClass'
    print("yes")
}
```

Comment: I'm still learning swift, but does `b is Array<SubClass>` work? [Type Casting : Checking Type](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/TypeCasting.html)

Comment: You've answered your own question, so what's the question?

Answer (score 0):

You can simply test it with `Array<String>() is Array<String>` but If you wanna know which type have any variable you can look at `d.dynamicType`

@crashmstr is right

Answer (score 0):

In your case `b` is an Array literal (a value type), not a reference type. So it can't call `isKindOfClass`.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
if let array = b as? Array<SuperClass>
{
    //perform some action
}
```